# Unity mobile game lag + profiler herlp

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, shader, profiler, lag

I am working on a simple game for mobile. Im a beginner/intermediate. My game is a simple endless runner like crazy taxi where you are jumping over other cars. For the environment I used a low polly free asset pack. The game runs perfectly on my laptop but when I built an apk and checked on a couple of devices its lagging a lot.

[image: This is what the game looks like.]

I used low poly assets so I thought it would not be an issue. I understand that mobiles have much less resources so how can I fix this problem or avoid it in the future? I see many top games on the app store with so much going on and many particle effects etc as well as many unity games so how do those people do that?

Attempt at resolution:

I have done a lot of research but I dont really understand. I read up on something about mobile shaders. So I thought I will change my shaders on the assets to mobile/diffuse from the standard but when i do that many assets lose their entire texture/color and become white.

The second thing I tried was the texture compression option on the build screen. There are options like DXT, ETC, ETC2, PVRTC, etc I tried all of them one by one but that did not seem to make a lot of difference.

Lastly I decided to have a look at the profiler. This is my first time using the profile. There really isnt much material online for beginners regarding such questions. In the profiler I notice that the most cpu use is because of Camera.Render and it usually takes average time 9ms. The rest of the things usually take substantially lower time with  most taking times like ~0.1. I dont know what 9ms means or if its a lot. I just have a simple camera script moving the camera behind the player.

[image: Profiler s/s]

I tried simplifying the environment and that caused the value to drop a bit, like ~7ms but I made the scene very simple and I dont want that I want to make a beautiful environment.

One last thing, At the moment since its an endless runner I have 5 prefabs for my roads and I am deleting and instantiating them. I know that is not good practice and instead I should just use a pool, but can this be the reason for the lag? The reason I havent done object pooling yet is that at the very beginning I would have to generate like 50 prefabs in my pool ten of each kind and thats just for 5 prefabs ideally I would like to have a wide variety of prefabs for my roads so the environment doesnt look repetitive. if anyone can help I would be forever indebted.

/e I have since set the settings to very low I have stopped auto generate lighting and also disabled shadows.

[image: This is a s/s of my stats.]

[image: s/s with simple cubes...]

This is starting to become increasingly hopeless. I dont see how theres any way I can get close to <50 batch count. The screen shot above uses simple 3d cube objects and that still gives me a batch count of 20-30. The minute I add some assets to make the scene prettier it goes up and starts lagging on my mobile.

Answer (score 2):

Drawcalls and shadows. I will give you better and bigger answer in a few hours because I'm currently working but read about drawcalls and in Edit-> Project Settings - > Quality - >Android set everything on low and disable shadows. Mobile devices are not good in rendering dynamic lights and shadows. Also - you should use pool system because with big prefabs it can really slow the game and make it freeze on prefab spawn. On low end-mid end devices drawcalls(currently called batches in unity) can be a huge bottleneck. Press stats in your unity3d game window and see how many batches do you have. For mobile it should be around 10 to 30 at max, at least in my experience.

Comment: Thanks I have now lowered the android settings to very low and have also turned off the shadows. In lighting I also unchecked auto generate. The stats show that I have over 700 batches :o ... I am desperately waiting for your detailed response and thanks once again. I have updated the original post with the stats s/s as well.

Comment: Is pooling going to reduce draw calls? or everytime I enable a prefab it will make those calls again? At the moment I have 5 road prefabs. If I pool them Ill have to atleast create 5 of each at the start of the game, so in the beginning Ill instantiate 25 if i have just 5 prefabs. What if I have more? like, 10-15 prefabs

Comment: how can i possibly get that low in my batches? When I removed everything except for my road, which albeit is a prefab ill change that for a normal 3d object but still I got 7-8 batches. When I put the car obstcles in my batches jumped to 40-50. Yes, the cars have child objects etc in them but they too were from a "low" poly count pack.

Comment: Sorry for not responding we have a release at work and I was forced to stay late night. Today I promise i will respond. I will be home in ~6 hours. Fast answer - pooling will not reduce drawcalls but c# has something called GC collector. When you creating object and then using Destroy a lot of memory needs to be managed and it work slow on mobile devices. For reducing drawcalls you need to look up texture atlases. If you have 200 objects in your scene and they all have the same material you will get from them only 1 drawcalls(not entirely true but close).

Comment: Still waiting for your response. If theres a reference place you can point me to that would be great as well. I just feel like if I know the whole picture one time I wont make the same mistakes again. I have been since playing around and when I reduced the batch count to below 200 for example it ran so much smother on the mobile. I read up on batching etc as well and since Im prototyping with free assets Im looking for those which use texture atlases etc!

Comment: I have some how managed to get the count to around ~100 by chopping changing assets trying to find other free assets with texture atlasing. I dont know anything about dessign so I cant seem to create texture atlas myself. The issue I have is if i remove all the assets but use simple 3d objects that I create in unity for side walks/roads etc my batch count is like 20+. How the hell can I possibly get near that number with using proper assets? If simple cube that I make myself will give 20-30 batches.

Comment: Still waiting for a detailed response Artur!

Answer (score 0):

these low poly assets actually are not so low poly for mobile and they have many different materials and consist of many child objects. Also if you use terrain change it to plane. And the heaviest thing is dynamic lightning and shadows.

Comment: That is the asset pack Im using. Its so beautiful but yes youre right it has many different materials and children objects especially. What does that mean though? Does it mean I cant use this pack? are child objects bad? I mean should I find an asset pack which has say... no child objects? yani, 1 house 1 object type?

Comment: Yes, I recognized this asset, I used it in one of my games. I know that one material is one drawcall, so the fewer materials the fewer drawcalls you have.  I think that those houses are too complex. Try to find some simple house model and test your game using it. But first of all pay attention to lightning settings

Comment: I never used it but maybe you'll want to try 
https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mesh.CombineMeshes.html
https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/31895

Comment: Can you please shed more light on how I should pay attention to the lighting? I have turned off auto generate lighting and I have also reduced the game quality for low on android devices. What more do I need to do for this simple game?